# urllib2 doesn't use proxy (Fiddler2), set using ProxyHandler

Tags: python, proxy, urllib2, fiddler

I have Fiddler2 listening on 0.0.0.0:8888.

```
try:
    data = '' 
    proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8888'})  //also tried {'http': 'http://127.0.0.1:8888/'}
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
    urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    req = urllib2.Request('http://www.google.com')
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    the_page = response.read()
        print the_page
except Exception, detail:
    print "Err ", detail
```

I don't see the GET or any request to google in Fiddler (but I can see other requests)
is there a way to debug it? is seems like python bypasses Fiddler or ignores the proxy.

I also configured WinHTTP to work with Fiddler -

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh winhttp set proxy 127.0.0.1:8888

Current WinHTTP proxy settings:

    Proxy Server(s) :  127.0.0.1:8888
    Bypass List     :  (none)
```

does is matter if the request it to a SSL address? (Fiddler supports https)

Thanks!

Comment: Just make sure you are able to talk to internet via your proxy on browser. Also have you set up any authentication? What exception does your code throw?

Comment: I see many requests\answers that my browser send and receive. I don't get any exception, the code is working, I just can't see the request on fieddler.

is there a way in which I can see what is going on in urllib2? kind of debugging what it's doing.

Comment: In order to check if the code is using the porxy I've changed fieddler to require proxy authentication and I had to use a user\pass on my browser when browsing, run the python code again and it worked, so it defiantly doesn't use the proxy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you can work with the opener directly instead of installing it. turn on your fiddler proxy listener on 8008 (i'm using WebScarab, but they're probably the same) then try this code exactly (also has cookies which you don't need, but lets try as-is and narrow it down later):

```
cj = cookielib.MozillaCookieJar(cookie_filename)
if os.access(cookie_filename, os.F_OK):
    cj.load()
proxy_handler = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'https': 'localhost:8008'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(
        proxy_handler,
        urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj)
    )
opener.addheaders = [
        ('User-agent', ('Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; '
                       'Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)'))
    ]
auth = urllib.urlencode({'email':email,'pass':passw})
data = opener.open('https://login.facebook.com/login.php',data=auth)
```

so - things i'm doing differently: direct usage of the opener, change the port to 8008, add cookies and use WebScarab. let me know which one of these did the trick for you...

Answer (score 3):

`proxy_bypass_registry` in urllib.py does not handle the `ProxyOverride` registry value properly:  it treats an empty override as *, i.e. bypass the proxy for all hosts.  This behavior does not match other programs (e.g. Chrome).

There are a number of possible workarounds:

1. Set `urllib.proxy_bypass = lambda h: 0` to disable bypass checking.
2. Specify the proxy settings in the `http_proxy` environment variable (`proxy_bypass_registry` is not called in this case).
3. In Fiddler2, go to the page Tools->Fiddler Options ...->Connections, remove the trailing semicolon from the value in the "IE should bypass Fiddler for ..." field and restart Fiddler2.

Answer (score 2):

In Fiddler2, go to the page *Tools -> Fiddler Options ... -> Connections*, remove the trailing semicolon from the value in the *IE should bypass Fiddler for ...* field and restart Fiddler2.

This solution is definitely works for me when I using urllib2 proxy, however I still don't understand why removing the trailing semicolon can solve it.

Answer (score 1):

btw, u need use http://www.google.com/ instead of http://www.google.com so that fiddler could figure you are requesting 'get /'

otherwise fiddler cannot figure out the uri. (u may get a 504 receive failure).