# Fiddler does not capture my script's requests

Tags: python, fiddler

my code:

`proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': '127.0.0.1:8888'})
opener = urllib2.build_opener(proxy)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com')
print f.read()`

this request does not show in Fiddler's capture, does anyone know how to configure Fiddler so that the request is captured?

EDIT: the request works, and I can see the contents. Also, if I close Fiddler, the request fails, as expected, because there is no proxy. It is just that I do not see anything in Fiddler.

EDIT2: I see traffic from a .NET test console application that I wrote. But I do not see traffic from my python script.

Comment: Does the request work though? (ie: is it actually grabbing google's contents?)

Comment: It sounds like you probably have a filter set: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/faq.asp#missingtraffic

Comment: thanks. I d not have a filter set... the "filters" tab has all the fields grayed out because the "use filters" checkbox is not checked. the "process filter" is not set either.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the exactly the same issue, when `fiddler2` opens, even I change 
`proxy = urllib2.ProxyHandler({'http': 'http://asdfl.com:13212/'})` (such none existing proxy server), it still can get the page content, I guess maybe when proxy server has been setup by `fiddler2`, `urllib2` totally ignore the `ProxyHandler` for some reason, still can't figure out.

---

I got it, check that thread in stackoverflow: 
[urllib2 doesn't use proxy (Fiddler2), set using ProxyHandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6554254/urllib2-doesnt-use-proxy-fiddler2-set-using-proxyhandler/8353622#8353622)

**In Fiddler2, go to the page `Tools->Fiddler Options ...->Connections`, remove the trailing semicolon from the value in the "`IE should bypass Fiddler for ...`" field and restart Fiddler2.**

this solution solved my problem, hope can help someone if you are struggling with it.

Comment: I was using python 2.7 and urllib2, trying to move to Python 3 and Requests, but Fiddler is NOT showing POST which is incredibly frustrating. I'm afraid your solution did not work for me.

Comment: I had to explicitly set session.proxies for my (localhost-defined) target host blah.com to { 'blah.com': 'https://127.0.0.1:8888'} - THEN Fiddler with Requests starts showing me POST, although it never had a problem showing me GET