# fiddler doesn't capture python http request?

Tags: python, http, fiddler

I've tried to use fiddle2 to debug one of my python program which makes http request and gets response. However I didn't see any traffic on fiddler no matter I ran python in command prompt or python GUI. Fiddle filter is not set, i.e., set to show all processes, I did see my browsers' traffic there.

Is there any settings I need to set?

Thanks.

Comment: This is the same as [Fiddler does not capture my script's requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7681305/fiddler-does-not-capture-my-scripts-requests).  If you want to use Fiddler, you can start with his proxy code, though he is having a problem actually seeing the request.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python does not use proxy by default, so fiddler cannot intercept its network traffic. You may need to change the Python program a little. Here is another thread on how to see proxy for Python programs [Proxy with urllib2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450132/proxy-with-urllib2).

Comment: I used proxy but still cannot capture any request.

Answer (score 5):

It will only work if you set Python to use Fiddler as a proxy.  It may be easier to use [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), which will let you monitor all HTTP traffic, without the need for proxies.

Comment: If you want to view https content, then fiddler is easier as wireshark can be hard to setup for that.